# Сайт на двух языках - как правильно разложить по папкам?

Tags: redirect, редирект, multilanguage

нубский вопрос - подскажите пожалуйста как сделать структуру сайта. Есть лендинг из одной страницы. Хочу русскую версию сделать основной но добавить и переключатель для "En".
Сайт простейший, никаких динамических загрузок и локализаций не нужно - просто сделаю две копии в разных папках. А как это правильно сделать? Разлождить по двум папкам

```
/ru/index.html 
/en/index.html
index.html
```

и в корне добавить ещё одну третью index.html, и на ней редирект

```
window.location.replace("/ru/index.html");
```

? Или поисковые машины такого не поймут и так не делается..

Или мне надо в корень положить русскую основную версию, а в подпапке разместить ещё английскую:

```
/index.html
/en/index.html
```

?

Как оно вообще обычно делается в этом случае..

Comment: Сделайте второй вариант, зачем лишний редирект?

Comment: @DaemonHK привет! Тоже так думаю - просто не знаю какой best-practice. Может там какой-то третий вариант.. (но по поддоменам разносить не надо, это более простой случай, с папками..)